# Dragg only in 1 div

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 divs 1 with a list of images and 1 with a div board.
The images are made draggable using:

```
 $('.image').draggable({ opacity: 0.9}).resizable();
```

the div board is on the left side (fixed width 80%) the images are on the right side (fixed width 20%)

i want to make it so if i drop the image in the div board it goes in the div board.
and not maintain div images.
and if its in the div board it only can be dragged in board and not back to images.

i tried

```
$('#board').droppable();
```

and

```
$( "#board" ).droppable({accept: "#draggable});
```

i have read diffrent pages but i can't get it to work

edit :
I have a button which prints the content of div board so it has to be in the div !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "#draggable" );
  }
});
```

or you can try like this

```
$('#droppable').droppable({ drop: Drop });

 function Drop(event, ui) {
     var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
     var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
 }
```

Comment: Nope it isnt makeing it going in the div board.       is it allowed to share the link to the page?

Comment: http://ve.svenboogaart.nl/test/   all the jquery is viewable at source code no external files used. the names are a bit diffrent then in the exmaple board = bord  and image = afbeelding

Comment: $('.afbeelding').draggable({  containment: '.bord' ,opacity: 0.5}).resizable();  gives the good effect (its only dragable in bord then ) but its still not in div bord

Comment: it worked i just thought it worked diffrent its dropped i checked with  $('.bord').droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });